# plotly cumulative animation does not work for subplot in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have 2 `plotly` plots with cumulative animations that work individually. But if I combine them using `subplot` they don't work. Is it possible to animate 2 combined plots? Following is a reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)

accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
    cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

library(MASS)
data(Traffic)


# data 1
Traffic1 <- Traffic %>%
  filter(year==1961) %>% 
  accumulate_by(~day)

# plot1
y_plot <- plot_ly(data = Traffic1,
                  x = ~day,
                  y = ~y,
                  frame = ~frame,
                  type = "scatter") %>%  
animation_slider(
  currentvalue = list(
    prefix = "Day"
  )
)


# data 2
Traffic2 <- Traffic %>%
  filter(year==1962) %>% 
  accumulate_by(~day)

# plot 2
y_plot2 <- plot_ly(data = Traffic2,
                  x = ~day,
                  y = ~y,
                  frame = ~frame,
                  type = "scatter") %>%  
  animation_slider(
    currentvalue = list(
      prefix = "Day"
    )
  )


# combined plot
subplot(y_plot, y_plot2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible. This question [Animated subplots in R with shared x axis (plotly package)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796720/animated-subplots-in-r-with-shared-x-axis-plotly-package) never got an answer. But, maybe there is an alternative using `ggplot2`, `ggplotly` and `facet_grid`.

You could try this:

```
#Create a new data frame
Traffic1$Traffic <- 1
Traffic2$Traffic <- 2
Traffic <- rbind(Traffic1, Traffic2)

gg <- ggplot(Traffic, aes(x=day, y=y)) +
    geom_point(aes(frame = frame), color = "blue") + facet_grid(Traffic~.) + theme_bw()
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: There is now an answer on https://community.plotly.com/t/is-it-possible-to-combine-plotly-cumulative-animations-in-subplot/9840/2